# @ManyToMany spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, update error - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Very well-known exception "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role". I read many blogs, many suggestions but they did not work for my case. 
Can anybody help me to understand how to resolve my issue ? 
All these work in WAR spring-webmvc (JSP view).
I have entities Person and Address. 1 Person can have many Addresses, at 1 Address can live many persons (family). Look :

```
package abc.def.data.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

/**
 */
@Entity
@Table( name = "PERSON" )
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*
     * ID of person.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private long id;

    /*
     * email and used as login of person.
     */
    @Column( name = "email", length = 128, nullable = false, unique = true )
    private String email;

    /*
     * Fullname of person.
     */
    @Column( name = "fullname", length = 128, nullable = true )
    private String fullName;

    /*
     * Person`s password. It is stored as encrypted value. Nobody know this value except person. There used
     * Spring encryption mechanism. Look at the
     */
    @Column( name = "password", length = 128, nullable = false )
    private String password;

    /*
     * 
     */
    @Column( name = "role", length = 16, nullable = false )
    private String role;

    @Column( name = "timezone", nullable = false )
    private int timezone;

    @Column( name = "created", nullable = false )
    @Type( type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime" )
    private DateTime created;

    @Column( name = "updated", nullable = false )
    @Type( type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime" )
    private DateTime updated;

    @Column( name = "isenabled", nullable = false )
    @Type( type = "true_false" )
    private boolean enabled;

    /*
     * Addresses of person. One person can has many addresses. In that time many persons can live in one
     * address (family).
     */
    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )
    @JoinTable( name = "PERSON_ADDRESS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn( name = "personid",
            referencedColumnName = "id" )}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn( name = "addressid",
            referencedColumnName = "id" )} )
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>(0);

    /**
     * closed Contructor. Need for JPA.
     */
    protected Person() {

    }

    /**
     * Public Contructor.
     * 
     * @param fullName
     * @param email
     * @param role
     * @param timezone
     * @param created
     * @param udated
     */
    public Person( String fullName, String email, String password, String role, int timezone,
            DateTime created, DateTime udated, boolean enabled ) {

        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.timezone = timezone;
        this.created = created;
        updated = udated;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Public Contructor without enabled status field. By default user is DISABLED here.
     * 
     * @param fullName
     * @param email
     * @param role
     * @param timezone
     * @param created
     * @param udated
     */
    public Person( String fullName, String email, String password, String role, int timezone,
            DateTime created, DateTime udated ) {

        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.timezone = timezone;
        this.created = created;
        updated = udated;
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return String.format(
                "Person [id=%s, fullName=%s, email=%s, password=%s, role=%s, timezone=%s, created=%s,"
                        + " updated=%s, enabled=%s, {address}]", id, fullName, email, password, role,
                timezone, created, updated, enabled );
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the id
     */
    public long getId() {

        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the fullName
     */
    public String getFullName() {

        return fullName;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {

        return email;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {

        return password;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the role
     */
    public String getRole() {

        return role;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the timezone
     */
    public int getTimezone() {

        return timezone;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the created
     */
    public DateTime getCreated() {

        return new DateTime( created, DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis( this.timezone ) );
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the updated
     */
    public DateTime getUpdated() {

        return new DateTime( updated, DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis( this.timezone ) );
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the enabled
     */
    public boolean isEnabled() {

        return enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return the addressCollection
     */
    public Set<Address> getAddresses() {

        //force clients through our add and remove methods
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet( addresses );
    }

    public void addAddress( Address address ) {

        //avoid circular calls : assumes equals and hashcode implemented
        if ( !addresses.contains( address ) ) {
            addresses.add( address );

            //add method to Product : sets 'other side' of association
            address.addPerson( this );
        }

    }

    public void removeAddress( Address address ) {

        //avoid circular calls : assumes equals and hashcode implemented
        if ( !addresses.contains( address ) ) {
            addresses.remove( address );

            //add method to Product : sets 'other side' of association
            address.removePerson( this );
        }

    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param id
     *            the id to set
     */
    public void setId( long id ) {

        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param fullName
     *            the fullName to set
     */
    public void setFullName( String fullName ) {

        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param email
     *            the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail( String email ) {

        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param password
     *            the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword( String password ) {

        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param role
     *            the role to set
     */
    public void setRole( String role ) {

        this.role = role;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param timezone
     *            the timezone to set
     */
    public void setTimezone( int timezone ) {

        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param created
     *            the created to set
     */
    public void setCreated( DateTime created ) {

        this.created = created;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param updated
     *            the updated to set
     */
    public void setUpdated( DateTime updated ) {

        this.updated = updated;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param enabled
     *            the enabled to set
     */
    public void setEnabled( boolean enabled ) {

        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param addressCollection
     *            the addressCollection to set
     */
    public void setAddresses( Set<Address> addressCollection ) {

        this.addresses = addressCollection;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) ( id ^ ( id >>> 32 ) );
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object obj ) {

        if ( this == obj ) return true;
        if ( obj == null ) return false;
        if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() ) return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if ( id != other.id ) return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Address :

```
package abc.def.data.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * Addresses of person. <br />
 * One person can has many addresses. In that time many persons can live in one address (family).
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table( name = "ADDRESS", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint( columnNames = {"country", "city", "street",
        "housenum"} )}, indexes = {} )
public class Address implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/*
 * Address ID.
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
private long id;

/*
 * Name of country.
 */
@Column( length = 128 )
private String country;

/*
 * Name of city.
 */
@Column( length = 64 )
private String city;

/*
 * Name of street.
 */
@Column( length = 64 )
private String street;

/*
 * Number of house.
 */
@Column( name = "housenum" )
private Integer houseNumber;

/*
 * Users who live at this Address.
 */
@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "addresses" )
public Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>( 0 );

/**
 * Getter.
 * 
 * @return the id
 */
public long getId() {

    return id;
}

/**
 * Getter.
 * 
 * @return the country
 */
public String getCountry() {

    return country;
}

/**
 * Getter.
 * 
 * @return the city
 */
public String getCity() {

    return city;
}

/**
 * Getter.
 * 
 * @return the street
 */
public String getStreet() {

    return street;
}

/**
 * Getter.
 * 
 * @return the houseNumber
 */
public Integer getHouseNumber() {

    return houseNumber;
}

/**
 * Getter.
 * 
 * @return the personCollection
 */
public Set<Person> getPersons() {

    return Collections.unmodifiableSet( persons );
}

/**
 * Setter.
 * 
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId( long id ) {

    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * Setter.
 * 
 * @param country
 *            the country to set
 */
public void setCountry( String country ) {

    this.country = country;
}

/**
 * Setter.
 * 
 * @param city
 *            the city to set
 */
public void setCity( String city ) {

    this.city = city;
}

/**
 * Setter.
 * 
 * @param street
 *            the street to set
 */
public void setStreet( String street ) {

    this.street = street;
}

/**
 * Setter.
 * 
 * @param houseNumber
 *            the houseNumber to set
 */
public void setHouseNumber( Integer houseNumber ) {

    this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
}

/**
 * Setter.
 * 
 * @param personCollection
 *            the personCollection to set
 */
public void setPersons( Set<Person> personCollection ) {

    this.persons = personCollection;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {

    return String.format( "Address [id=%s, country=%s, city=%s, street=%s, houseNumber=%s, {person}]",
            id, country, city, street, houseNumber );
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void addPerson( Person person ) {

    //assumes equals and hashcode implemented: avoid circular calls
    if ( !persons.contains( person ) ) {
        persons.add( person );

        //add method to Product : sets 'other side' of association
        person.addAddress( this );
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void removePerson( Person person ) {

    //assumes equals and hashcode implemented: avoid circular calls
    if ( !persons.contains( person ) ) {
        persons.remove( person );
    }

    //add method to Product : sets 'other side' of association
    person.removeAddress( this );
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {

    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) ( id ^ ( id >>> 32 ) );
    return result;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals( Object obj ) {

    if ( this == obj ) return true;
    if ( obj == null ) return false;
    if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() ) return false;
    Address other = (Address) obj;
    if ( id != other.id ) return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

In case New registration and new person and new address - no problem. It passed find. 
In PersonService @Service I have :

```
    // create new Person 
Person newPerson = new Person( fullName, email, password, role, timezone, created, udated, true );

    // add addresses - it is possible have more 1 address in registration
    newPerson.setAddresses( (Set<Address>) addrList );

    try {
        newPerson = personRepository.save( newPerson );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        actionResult.setError( true );
        actionResult.addErrorItem( "error", e.getMessage() );
    }
    LOG.debug( "Created new person : {}", newPerson.toString() );
    actionResult.setObject( newPerson );

    return actionResult;

    /*
 * Check given addresses for existing.
 */
private Collection<Address> checkAddresses( Set<Address> addrList, Person newPerson ) {

    Set<Address> newAddresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    Address addr = null;
    for (Address address : addrList) {
        addr =


addressRepository.findByCountryAndCityAndStreetAndHouseNumber( address.getCountry(), address.getCity(), address.getStreet(), address.getHouseNumber() );
        if ( addr != null ) {
            addr.getPersons().size();
        }

        addr = addr == null ? address : addr;
        newAddresses.add( addr );

        LOG.debug( "checked address {}", addr.toString() );
    }
    return newAddresses;
}
```

personRepository :

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

In case new user enter existing address - it checks (found) in DB. When it found it have to be added to newPerson() . In this case exception arise. 
I tried use address.getPerson().size - also exception .

Also I do not want use EAGER. is It possible ?

Comment: Just make your Service method @Transactional.

Comment: Yep, I did so and did 
    @ Override
    @ Transactional
    public Person registerPerson( String email, String password, Set<Address> addrList ) {
....
it does not help

Comment: try to use `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`, not the on in `javax....`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an active transaction or open thread-bound EntityManager, Spring Data JPA will create a new EntityManager for each call on a repository. Then it closes the EntityManager before returning, leading to the exception you're getting when Hibernate tries to lazy-load.

There are two ways to deal with this. One is to use transactions, possibly by applying `@Transactional` as appropriate. The other is to use `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`, which will create a thread-bound EntityManager at the beginning of each request and hold it open for the entire request. In this case I think a transaction is called for because you're doing an INSERT that depends on previous SELECTs. `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` is very handy for using lazy-loaded collections in views, but it doesn't provide any transaction management.